# how to automate Googleplay monthly payout reports?

Tags: google-play, merchant-account, google-play-services

Regarding accessing  googleplay payout reports api, 
 to download monthly  payout reports, google provide api
https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API

But this api requires Merchant key.  But in our merchant account I can't see merchant_key, so I can't download the  payout reports based on the above api.

Like AutoIngestion.class from Apple, is there any Google play Api to 
download reports for particular merchant account.?

Our project requires to download monthly sales reports automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi again, I found this. It seems that it is possible somehow, but how exactly I don't know yet. Look at this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140728/getting-statistics-from-google-play-developers-with-an-api

Comment: @BabakBandpay Not yet.If you find something Kindly add here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [gsutil tool](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)? According to [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017?hl=en) it is used to automate the download of sales and payout reports.