# Displaying Number of App Download in Android Application

Tags: android, count

I have created an app, the requirement is to display a Total number application download count in Main dashboard screen of app.

Is there a way or any API available for doing such thing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting statistics from Google Play Developers with an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140728/getting-statistics-from-google-play-developers-with-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, google provides a beautiful solution to this with its Embed API. The following is the link to that API.
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

Comment: Bro , I want to display total app download count in app : What the source ?

Comment: You can add Google analytics to your application. It will allow you to see the number of downloads of your app. The above link is an API for the same.