# Get download data from google play through an API for my own app

Tags: google-play

Is there a way for me to programmatically pull download data from google play for my own android app?

I want to track daily downloads through my own analytics portal.. Currently I couldn't figure out how I'd get this data. Does google play expose such an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar questions has been asked/answered here:
[Getting statistics from Google Play Developers with an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140728/getting-statistics-from-google-play-developers-with-an-api)

You could also look at the 
[Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) documentation, however this might be specific to your Analytics account.